# Mark messages as read before receive

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a problem with message reading via IMAP protocol. When I connect to store, messages are marked as read.

```
public class MailServiceImpl implements MailService {

public List<MailParser> receiveMessages(ServiceEmail se) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    final Session session = session(se.getProtocol().name(), se.getHost(), se.getPort(), se.isSsl());

    final Store store = session.getStore(se.getProtocol().name());
    store.connect(se.getHost(),
            !StringUtils.isEmpty(se.getUsername()) ? se.getUsername() : se.getEmail(),
            se.getPassword());
    final Folder inbox = store.getFolder(INBOX_FOLDER);
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

    final Message[] unreadMessages = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));

    final List<MailParser> parsedMessages = Lists.newArrayList();

    for (final Message message : unreadMessages) {
        message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, true);
        parsedMessages.add(MailParser.create(message));
    }

    inbox.close(true);
    store.close();

    return parsedMessages;
}

/**
 * {@see https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/package-summary.html}
 *
 * properties.put("mail.debug", "true"); - set this if you need to debug
 */
private Session session(String protocol, String host, Integer port, Boolean isSSL) {
    final Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.store.protocol", protocol);
    properties.put(String.format("mail.%s.host", protocol), host);
    properties.put(String.format("mail.%s.port", protocol), String.valueOf(port));
    if (protocol.equalsIgnoreCase(EmailProtocol.imap.name())) configureImapSessionProperties(properties);
    if (isSSL) properties.put(String.format("mail.%s.ssl.enable", protocol), String.valueOf(isSSL));
    properties.put("mail.debug", "true");

    return Session.getInstance(properties);
}

private void configureImapSessionProperties(Properties properties) {
    properties.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    properties.put("mail.imap.connectionpoolsize", "30");
    properties.put("mail.imap.connectiontimeout", "60000");
    properties.put("mail.imap.timeout", "60000");
    properties.put("mail.imap.writetimeout", "60000");
}
}
```

Debug output:

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.5<br/>
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers<br/>
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers<br/>
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name:<br/> {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], <br/>com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], <br/>com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle],<br/>com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], <br/>com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], <br/>com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}<br/>
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: <br/>{imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], <br/>imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], <br/>smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], <br/>pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], <br/>smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}<br/>
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map<br/>
DEBUG: getProvider() returning <br/>javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]<br/>
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384<br/>
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false<br/>
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000<br/>
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1<br/>
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10<br/>
DEBUG IMAP: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure<br/>
DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "imap.mail.ru", port 993, isSSL <br/>true
* OK Welcome<br/>
A0 CAPABILITY<br/>
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 ID XLIST UIDPLUS UNSELECT MOVE LIST-STATUS AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 LIST-STATUS<br/>
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed<br/>
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN<br/>
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: XOAUTH2<br/>
DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=imap.mail.ru, user=adv@jeffit.ru, password=<non-null><br/>
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed<br/>
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 OK Authentication successful<br/>
A2 CAPABILITY<br/>
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 ID XLIST UIDPLUS UNSELECT MOVE LIST-STATUS<br/>
A2 OK CAPABILITY completed<br/>
DEBUG IMAP: connection available -- size: 1<br/>
A3 SELECT INBOX<br/>
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft \Seen)<br/>
* 4 EXISTS<br/>
* 0 RECENT<br/>
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1450860102]<br/>
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft)]<br/>
* OK [UIDNEXT 109]<br/>
A3 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed<br/>
A4 SEARCH UNSEEN ALL<br/>
* SEARCH<br/>
A4 OK SEARCH completed<br/>
<p>
<code>unreadMessages</code> is empty sometime.
</p>
```

Comment: I'm unsure what you're asking here.  Your code is marking all messages as seen as soon as you retrieve them.  What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: What do you think `message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, true);` does??

Comment: I asked about <code>unreadMessages</code>, this array is empty before SEEN them

Comment: Also when I delete from loop SEEN flag, nothing new happened because messages are already read

Comment: The server says there are no unseen messages.  If you think the server is lying to you, you need to complain to the server vendor.  Why do you believe that there should be unseen messages?  Are you sure some other program is not accessing the mailbox and marking the messages as seen?

Comment: @BillShannon Yes. I'm sure. I sent messages to server, and they are new before this code is launched. And sometime this code found unseen.

Comment: You mean sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't?  That could be a server bug, but it sounds more like some other program, or another instance of your program, is reading the messages.  If you can, try creating a new account so you know no other program is monitoring it and see if your program works with the new account.